# Display content before <a> href attribute when using the "woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item" action hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

On my website I added a hover effect to show a wishlist icon, but when you click the icon, you are transfered to the product page, instead of running the ajax script to add the current product inside the wishlist.

I know that I can easily do this with `insertAfter` jQuery but before I do I wanted to know if there is a "cleaner" solution in WooCommerce?

I also tried with CSS `pointer-events:none` but that doesn't have the desired result.

Currently this is the markup:

```html
<a>
    <div class"wishlist">My icon</div>
    <img>
    <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">
</a>
```

How can I edit WooComerce with hooks and filters so that I can move the `<div class"wishlist">My icon</div>` outside of `<a>` ?

Like:

```html
<div class"wishlist">My icon</div>
<a>
    <img>
    <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">
</a>
```

Right now I use the action `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item` to show the wishlist icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using hooks without a priority number, like:

```php
function action_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item() {
    echo '<div class"wishlist">My icon</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'action_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );
```

Priority 10 will be used by default in WooCommerce.

---

However, in */templates/content-product.php* we can see that the callback function `woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open` already contains priority 10:

```php
 * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );
```

In */includes/wc-template-hooks.php* there is:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
```

So you have to **make sure that your custom code is executed before the default actions**, this can be done by adjusting the priority number, for example to 1:

```php
function action_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item() {
    echo '<div class"wishlist">My icon</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'action_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 1 );
```